# Getting an error "Is null or not an object"

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <table class="table" id="table_id">
    <thead>
      <th data-dynatable-column="pt_name">Name</th>
      <th data-dynatable-column="unit">Unit</th>
      <th data-dynatable-column="room">Room</th>
      <th data-dynatable-column="fin">FIN</th>
      <th data-dynatable-column="line_type">Line Type</th>
      <th data-dynatable-column="line_loc">Location</th>
      <th data-dynatable-column="line_days">Est Days in Place</th>
      <th data-dynatable-column="insert_date">Insertion Date</th>
      <th data-dynatable-column="last_dsg_change">Last Dsg Change</th>
      <th data-dynatable-column="hosp_insertion">Hospital Insert</th>
      <th data-dynatable-column="reason">Reason</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody></tbody>
  </table>

  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json2/20130526/json2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="libs/jquery-dynatable/jquery.dynatable.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function(){

        $.get("model/20_mp_cc_get_cvcs.json",function (data) {

          $('#table_id').dynatable({
            dataset: {
              records: data.cvc_list.qual
            }
          });
        })

    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and a portion of the 20_mp_cc_get_cvcs.json is:

```
{
    "cvc_list": {
        "cvc_cnt": 12,
        "patient_cnt": 6,
        "qual": [
            {
                "dg_id": 20627424964.0,
                "enc_id": 82048822.0,
                "fin": "700001703",
                "hosp_insertion": "y",
                "insert_date": "05/29/2014",
                "insert_dt_tm": "/date(2014-05-29t00:00:00.000-04:00)/",
                "last_dsg_change": "",
                "line_days": 31,
                "line_loc": "upper",
                "line_type": "cvc",
                "pers_id": 69935620.0,
                "pt_name": "buildtest , domainone",
                "reason": "",
                "room": "1rmh",
                "unit": "1rmh"
            },
            {
                "dg_id": 20627428586.0,
                "enc_id": 82048822.0,
                "fin": "700001703",
                "hosp_insertion": "n",
                "insert_date": "05/21/2014",
                "insert_dt_tm": "/date(2014-05-21t00:00:00.000-04:00)/",
                "last_dsg_change": "",
                "line_days": 39,
                "line_loc": "rt., brachial",
                "line_type": "picc",
                "pers_id": 69935620.0,
                "pt_name": "buildtest , domainone",
                "reason": "",
                "room": "1rmh",
                "unit": "1rmh"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I keep getting an error that says cvc_list.qual is "null or not an object".  This is not happening in all browsers.  Just in our Citrix VM running IE10 with Document Mode IE7.  What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: What does `console.log(data)` say `data` is?

Comment: [`$.get`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) may or may not be correctly interpreting your data as JSON (looks like it depends on the MIME type), and hence may or may not be parsing it as JSON (and is instead keeping it as a string). You might want to add the `'json'` parameter for `$.get`'s last parameter of `dataType` to ensure it is parsed as JSON (per the last example in the linked docs). You should also follow @josh's suggestion to do `console.log(data)` to see what you're actually getting, or put a breakpoint in your `$.get` callback.

Answer (score 0):

`$.get` might not gurantee a JSON parse, better to use the full version -

```
$(function(){
    $.ajax({
         url: "model/20_mp_cc_get_cvcs.json",
         dataType: "json",
         type: "get",
         success: function(data){
             $('#table_id').dynatable({
                  dataset: {
                        records: data.cvc_list.qual
                  }
             });
         }
    });


});
```

There is also a `JSON.parse` method available in IE7, so you can also use that one to parse on your side. So you might do something like this -

```
    $.get("model/20_mp_cc_get_cvcs.json",function (data) {
      if (typeof data == "string"){
          data = JSON.parse(data);
      }
      $('#table_id').dynatable({
        dataset: {
          records: data.cvc_list.qual
        }
      });
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `dataType` attribute in your ajax call.
As per jQuery docs, by default its value is evaluated based on guess;

> dataType (default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html))
>
> Type: String The type of data that you're expecting back from the
>   server. If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the
>   MIME type of the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4
>   JSON will yield a JavaScript object, in 1.4 script will execute the
>   script, and anything else will be returned as a string).

Specify dataType : json in your ajax call if you are expecting a json from server side.

Or alternatively you can use, [jQuery.parseJson](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/)

**Sol#1**

$.get("model/20_mp_cc_get_cvcs.json",function (data) {

```
      $('#table_id').dynatable({
        dataset: {
          records: data.cvc_list.qual
        }
      });
    }, "json");  // Tell jQuery that you are expecting json.
```

**Sol#2**

```
$.get("model/20_mp_cc_get_cvcs.json", function (data) {
          var json = jQuery.parseJSON(data);  // parse it 
          $('#table_id').dynatable({
            dataset: {
              records: json.cvc_list.qual   // use the json here
            }
          });
        });
```